# Stored procedure / query needing additional field in 2% of all use-cases. Best practises?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, design-patterns

I have a stored procedure used in aound 50 different places within a large application. One of these 50 contexts would require an additional field from this procedure.

I can think of two different approaches:

1. Update the stored procedure to return the missing field.
   That means that I will always request some additional data that will be useless in the 49 of 50 other use-cases.
2. Let the stored procedure as it is (withouth the needed additional data).
   And when I need the additional data (1 of 50 use-cases), query the base after the SP returns to enhance the SP result set into a dedicated DTO.
   In this case I would add this extra code into my business layer.
   That means extra code and getting all the data in two queries instead of one.

What would be the best practices?

Comment: How complicated is the stored procedure itself? What rdbms are you working with? How will adding the column effect the overall performance of the parts of the application that don't use it?

Comment: If the procedure itself is simple (and by simple I mean basically a single select statement - something that can be translated to a view) - a good option might be creating a view for that stored procedure, and add another stored procedure based on the same view to get all the columns + the one extra.

Comment: Using MYSQL rdbm.
The procedure is a >100 lines thing. I ll be happy if I can avoid modifying it. But if it appears that the best practises would consist in updating it, I ll do it nontheless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best practice" in my opinion is not a hugely useful phrase - it depends on what you're trying to optimize for.

If your application code can handle the additional field, there are many arguments for just adding that field to the result set. It's the least effort, and the least complexity. There are no surprises - it's common for stored procedures to return a result set, and the application code to then decide what to do with that result set (including ignoring some columns). As a general "best practice" principle, having a single stored procedure return a full result set, and having the client code decide what to do with that result set, makes the proc easy to use and re-use, and as long as you don't change the result set, you can change the implementation of the procedure. The overhead of transferring a few extra bytes is negligible in most cases - if it *is* a problem, you have bigger problems!

EDIT in response to comment from @vvgiri:

There may be a performance impact if you have to join to other tables to get the additional data. In practice, as long as the join is a simple "foreign key/primary key" join, it will likely have no measurable impact unless you have *huge* data sets, but it's worth testing.

The problem with that approach is that you may need to test all 50 places where the stored proc is used. You don't write about this in your question; if it's not an issue, I would just add the extra field.

If it *is* a problem, I'd consider the maintainability and "least surprise" factors. Without specifics, it's hard to say whether I'd be surprised if client code calls one stored procedure, and then uses the result of that to get more data. But if that would be surprising, I'd consider writing a new procedure, with a name that makes clear why it exists. That procedure should probably call the original proc, and then do the enriching, returning the result set your client code needs.

This approach means your client code stays "clean" - no surprises or special cases. It re-uses the original proc - no duplication. It may be slower than modifying the original proc, but no slower than your "option 2".

Comment: If the additional fields that you require for that specific scenario are not already part of the underlying tables being queried, i.e, additional join(s) required to satisfy the scenario, then you should NOT touch the existing stored procedures because there WILL be a performance impact on the other 49 scenarios which is unnecessary. If the additional join(s) are required, you should create a new StoredProc for handling the specific scenario. If this does not apply to your case, @Neville Kuyt's response is perfect.

Comment: If that extra column is, say, `int` (Which has a storage size of 4 bytes), and the stored procedure returns 1000 rows, that's only 4000 extra bytes. But what if that extra column is an `nvarchar(4000)`, which is half full (meaning 2002 bytes per row on average), Now if the stored procedure returns 1000 rows that's 200,200 extra bytes per execution. If we're talking about an application with a lot of users, that extra traffic load itself might become a significant bottle neck - Regardless of the extra time it might take the database to join that column (which is usually negligible).

Comment: I respectfully disagree. 200K of extra data going across the network should not make a big difference - there are of course extreme cases, but if that's the case, the OP has bigger problems.

Comment: That's 200K per request. If you're system have 100 requests per hour, it's nothing. If you have 100 per second, that's a completely different story :-)

Comment: In my case, no additional join, not a lot of extra data.
SP probably a pain to update but as mentionned, if it's considered a better practise to update the SP, I ll do it.
Thx for your comments guys. I understand from your comments that the answer to this question depnds of the application/use cases context.

Answer (score 0):

I think personally that I'd just include a variable in my procedure that I can set on my execution query if I want the extra columns, using this variable to adjust the output as needed

Comment: ....Which would force you to either use an optional variable or change all the calls to the procedure. Given the fact the OP didn't specify the rdbms nor the application, we don't know if it's possible to use an optional parameter not in the database and not in the code. Having said that, assuming it's possible it's a perfectly valid proposal.